# JQPlot chart not displaying

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I've checked the other similar questions, but still can't track down the source of this problem.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jquery/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/jquery/jquery.jqplot.css" />

</head>
<body>

<div id="chart2" style="height:300px;width:500px; "></div>

</body>

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {

   var line1 = [['Nissan', 4],['Porche', 6],['Acura', 2],['Aston Martin', 5],['Rolls Royce', 6]];

    $('#chart2').jqplot([line1], {
        title:'Bar Chart with Varying Colors',
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                // Set the varyBarColor option to true to use different colors for each bar.
                // The default series colors are used.
                varyBarColor: true
            }
        },
        axes:{
            xaxis:{
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
            }
        }
    });


});

</script>

</html>
```

The problem is, nothing displays other than the chart canvas. There are no errors logged in the console, and the source files were loaded. I moved the call the .jqplot to below the chart2 div because a user believed this was necessary, though I don't believe that to be the case since we're using $(document).ready(function()...

Any idea where the problem lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

Needed to include the additional renderers which had been specified in the call the .jqplot.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jquery/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jquery/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
```